# macOS Jenkins uses system ruby instead of installed ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins, rvm

A client has jenkins setup on a macOS machine. It's doing iOS builds and uses bundler to install some gems. One gem recently started requiring a dependency which in turn requires ruby >= 2.1

```
Installing jwt 2.1.0
Gem::InstallError: jwt requires Ruby version >= 2.1.
An error occurred while installing jwt (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

For one, I've installed rvm and ruby 2.1.0 on the macOS machine

```
osxbuildserver:~ jenkins$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

and for the ssh login user it shows up fine. The issue is that even tough Jenkins runs under the same jenkins user

```
root            15102     1 15102      0    0 Ss     ??    0:00.04 sshd: jenkins [priv] 
jenkins         15106 15102 15102      0    0 S      ??    0:00.03 sshd: jenkins@ttys000
```

it still uses the system ruby which is 2.0.0. In one of the builds I've added a shell script with `ruby -v`

```
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe     /var/folders/6v/xlw3p2pn47d2jl_jghf25dn00000gr/T/hudson73325394438439334.sh    
+ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

Calling

```
ssh jenkins@osxbuild "echo $PATH"
```

from my local machine, returns the incorrect path

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but login in with the same user is fine

```
osxbuildserver:~ jenkins$ echo $PATH
/Users/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/Users/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/Users/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin.... etc
```

I've already tried the answer from here [Jenkins using System Ruby - use rvm ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624324/jenkins-using-system-ruby-use-rvm-ruby) but it didn't help.

my .bash_profile contents

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$JAVA_HOME
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=$HOME/tesseract-ocr

source ~/.profile
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: Does your `.bash_profile` has this line `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`?

Comment: It wasn't. I added it and restarted but doesn't help. I'll update the question with the contents of my .brash_profile

Comment: After adding the line you have to relogin

Comment: I've restarted the machine, it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

The question is quite old  but probably somebody will use my solution.
I copied everything that gave me `echo $PATH`. Then I opened Jenkin's configuration and found "Global properties".
I added PATH and as a value I added value from terminal.
[image: jenkins environment set up]

Comment: I couldn't found any solution about Jenkins picking up the system Ruby and wasted hours. This worked finally. Thanks

Comment: where is the  "Global properties" I can't found it

Answer (score 0):

I messed up with this problem for a few days, finally its working well, thanks to the inspiration from [@BlackRainbow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64477594/8329034)

**What Exactly I Do**:

> 1. Used [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme) to manage my Ruby environment
> 2. Open terminal and execute `echo $PATH`
> 3. Copy the result and paste to Jenkinsfile
> 4. Re-try to build your pipeline
> 5. Thats it, and its working well in my enviroment

**Attachment:**

> *Step 1-2 To Configure Ruby & Get Path Env* [image: -]

---

> *Step 2-3 To Configure Jenkinsfile* [image: -]

---

> *Step 4 Build Pipeline* [image: -]